# React getting Syntax error on file Cell.js in the react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs

m following a tutorial by Ania Kubow but I ran into a bug if I try to run the react app. The error is in the Cell.js file of the project and I can't figure out why.

Here's the code:

```
const Cell = ({ id , cell, setCells, go, setGo, cells, winningMessage }) => {
    
    const handleClick = (e) => {
        const taken = e.target.firstChild.classList.contains("circle") ||
              e.target.firstChild.classList.contains("cross")
        
        if (!taken) {
            if (go === "circle") {
                e.target.firstChild.classList.add("circle")
                handleCellChange("circle")
                setGo("cross")
            }
            if (go === "cross") {
                e.target.firstChild.classList.add("cross")
                handleCellChange("cross")
                setGo("circle")
        }
    }
        const handleCellChange = (className) => {
           const nextCells = cells.map((cell, index) => {
                if (index === id) {
                    return className
                } else {
                    return cell
                }
            })
           setCells(nextCells)
        }
        
        return ( 
            <div className = "square" id={id} onClick={!winningMessage && handleClick}></div>
                <div className={cell}></div>
    ) 
}

export default Cell
```

Any help wouold be appreciated, I'm a React beginner and need much to learn.

Comment: Providing the error would be helpful

Comment: Please mention the error you age getting here

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a curly bracket in the function `handleClick`
Also, a React component can return a single child element. To solve the issue of returning multiple markups, you can use `React.Fragment` to wrap your component. This will trick React algorithm, as you will be returning a single child element, but on HTML side, there will be no visible element wrapping your children. To learn more, visit [Fragment Documentation](https://react.dev/reference/react/Fragment)

Here is your fixed changes:

```js
const Cell = ({ id, cell, setCells, go, setGo, cells, winningMessage }) => {

    const handleClick = (e) => {
        const taken = e.target.firstChild.classList.contains("circle") ||
            e.target.firstChild.classList.contains("cross")

        if (!taken) {
            if (go === "circle") {
                e.target.firstChild.classList.add("circle")
                handleCellChange("circle")
                setGo("cross")
            }
            if (go === "cross") {
                e.target.firstChild.classList.add("cross")
                handleCellChange("cross")
                setGo("circle")
            }
        }
    }
    const handleCellChange = (className) => {
        const nextCells = cells.map((cell, index) => {
            if (index === id) {
                return className
            } else {
                return cell
            }
        })
        setCells(nextCells)
    }

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
          <div className="square" id={id} onClick={!winningMessage && handleClick}></div>
          <div className={cell}></div>
       </React.Fragment>
    )
}

export default Cell;
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you mention the error here. But looking at the code there is one wrong thing and it's that it doesn't allow to return two items in single return.

please wrap your both div into another div or <>{YOUR DIVs}</>